# Pausing progress bar as well as div rotating

Tags: jquery, rotation

I'm looking to pause the progress bar on hover, the same way as with the div content (which you'll notice pauses despite the progress bar progressing).

Here is the JSFiddle below: http://jsfiddle.net/LmuR7/1/ (using plugin from here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/29/quotes-rotator/)

And the extra code added to allow for *pause on hover of the content*:

```
// Pause on hover in, resume on hover out
this.$items.hover(function(){
   THIS.paused = true;
}, function(){
   THIS.paused = false;
});`
```

Comment: +1: Down-vote seems harsh. You have provide a JSFiddle and pretty clear explanation of what you need. Downvoter care to explain?

Comment: Probably because I didn't cite where the plugin is coming from in my original post. Even though that the JSFiddle quite clearly links to it (so I did not see the need to double state). It's not as if I removed the copyrights and claimed it to be my own. Downvoter could have assumed I was attempting to claim the code as my own, when really it is a public resource in which I am asking help to modify. I'm not where the malice is in that myself.

Comment: Found and fixed the problems (noted in the answer). Also restructured the code so that the extra timer was not needed (as it was really only checking for a change in the `paused` flag). Hope you like it. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem is that the progress bar uses CSS animation and not code. To stop it you need to work out where it is, then to restart it you need to work out how long it should take to finish.

I have restructered the pause/resume code, so that an extra timer was not needed. The previous bug I had was down to `'width ' + THIS.options.interval - elapsed` evaluating `'width ' + THIS.options.interval` as a string first (just missing some brackets):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmuR7/5/

```
        // Pause on hover in, resume on hover out
        this.$items.hover(function () {
            THIS._pause(true);
        }, function () {
            THIS._pause(false);
        });
```

### _pause method:

```
    _pause: function (pause) {
        var THIS = this;
        if (THIS.paused != pause) {
            THIS.paused = pause;
            if (THIS.support) {
                var elapsed = (new Date()) - THIS.start;
                //console.log("elapsed: " + elapsed);
                var percentage = elapsed / THIS.options.interval * 100;
                if (pause) {
                    // Stop the progress animation at its current position
                    THIS.$progress.css({
                        transition: 'none',
                        width: percentage + "%"
                    });
                } else {
                    // Restart the progress bar based on remaining time left
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        //console.log("duration: " + (THIS.options.interval - elapsed));
                        THIS.$progress.css({
                            transition: 'width ' + (THIS.options.interval - elapsed) + 'ms linear',
                            width: '100%'
                        });
                    }, 25);
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

### _startRotator changes:

This needed an extra check so that the progress bar was not reset each time (if paused).

```
    _startRotator: function () {
        var THIS = this;
        this.start = new Date();
        if (this.support) {
            this._startProgress();
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            if (THIS.support && !THIS.paused) {
                THIS._resetProgress();
            }
            if (!THIS.paused) {
                THIS._next();
            }
            THIS._startRotator();
        }, THIS.options.interval);
    },
```

Comment: Slightly less smooth than the original (on the transition), and the hovering is still a bit buggy. But thanks for the effort, I might be able to work it out from here!

Comment: The speed will increase depending on the remaining time. To get the timing right on hover would require more of a re-write as it is based on quite a simple one-shot timer, constantly repeated at fixed intervals. Good luck :)